# How to save GIF with added watermark text with .NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I try to use code below which adds watermark text to captured frames of GIF. When I save source image as ImageFormat.Gif it has no effect. If I save it as ImageFormat.Jpeg it saves last frame with added watermark.
Is there a way to achieve this like that or better use external library package?

```
using (var img = Image.FromStream(memoryStream))
{
    int numberOfFrames = img.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Time);
    Image[] frames = new Image[numberOfFrames];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFrames; i++)
    {
        img.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Time, i);
        frames[i] = (Image)img;

        using (var graphic = Graphics.FromImage(frames[i]))
        {
            var font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 16, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            var color = Color.Black;
            var brush = new SolidBrush(color);
            var point = new Point(2, 2);

            graphic.DrawString("Example text as watermark", font, brush, point);
        }
    }
    //img.Save(newStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    img.Save(newStream, ImageFormat.Gif);
}
tempFileUri = $"data:{format};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(newStream.ToArray())}";
```

Answer (score 2):

I have just added a watermark to an image in a ".NET 5 project" by using this 3rd party library here: https://github.com/LazZiya/ImageResize.

I used the code sample provided on the github page and it worked straight away.

```
using(var img = Image.FromFile(@"wwwroot\images\image-file.jpg"))
{
    var tOps = new TextWatermarkOptions
    {
        // Change text color and opacity
        // Text opacity range depends on Color's alpha channel (0 - 255)
        TextColor = Color.FromArgb(50, Color.White),
        
        // Add text outline
        // Outline color opacity range depends on Color's alpha channel (0 - 255)
        OutlineColor = Color.FromArgb(255, Color.Black),

        // Change image watermark location
        Location = TargetSpot.BottomRight
    };
    
    img.AddTextWatermark("This is some watermark text!", tOps)
       .SaveAs(@"wwwroot\images\new-image.jpg");
}
```

Notice, to change the location of the text, you can set the `Location` property in the `TextWatermarkOptions` class. In the code above, its set to `BottomRight` but this can be `Center`

To install this package via nuget:

```
Install-Package LazZiya.ImageResize
```

Comment: Have you tried it with GIF? It seems it is not showing watermark with memory stream save, and second case saving to file takes only one frame, same as I mentioned in question

Comment: Thank you @Ocean Airdrop for mentioning this package, _I am the owner of it_.  @ w3p I will work for an update to support animated gif, and will inform you here.

Comment: Thank @Laz Ziya for your project.  Great work.

Comment: it is available now, kindly see my answer below for details :)

Answer (score 2):

Animated gif support is now available :)

Currently it is available in [v4.0.0-preview1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LazZiya.ImageResize/4.0.0-preview1), and can be used same as `Image` files, the only difference is to use `AnimatedImage` instead of `Image` as below:

```
PM > Install-Package LazZiya.ImageResize -Pre
```

> Add -Pre to install latest preview version

Load your animated image and edit as below:

```cs
using LazZiya.ImageResize.Animated;

using(var img = AnimatedImage.FromFile("wwwroot/images/animated-image-file.gif"))
{    
    img.AddTextWatermark("This is some watermark text!")
       .SaveAs("wwwroot/images/new-animated-image.gif");
}
```

See the [docs](https://docs.ziyad.info/en/LazZiya.ImageResize/v4.0/index.md) for more details.

Comment: Great stuff @Laz.  Just wanted to say thanks for supporting the community like this.

Comment: @OceanAirdrop it is my pleasure, gald to help :)